# Autodesk Forge Reality capture photo scene id does not exist

Tags: postman, autodesk-forge

I am trying auto desk forge api to create a mesh from images but unable to upload photos getting error code 19.

I tried-

```
curl -X POST \


https://developer.api.autodesk.com/photo-to-3d/v1/file \
  -H 'authorization: Bearer xxx' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -H 'postman-token: e25fbfb0-3754-e48f-4f0f-cac34bfd9df2' \
  -F 'file[0]=@IMG_20200930_180808.jpg' \
  -F 'file[1]=@IMG_20200930_180814.jpg' \
  -F 'file[2]=@IMG_20200930_180820.jpg' \
  -F 'file[3]=@IMG_20200930_180830.jpg' \
  -F type=image \
  -F photosceneid=<some sceneid>
```

Please suggest if any thing missing, I have to use it through postman.

Comment: According to [their documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/reality-capture/v1/developers_guide/error-codes/), error code 19 means `Specified Photoscene ID doesn't exist in the database`. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

As Christian mentioned, code 19 means that the *photoscene* you are referring to does not exist. Make sure to create the photoscene using the [POST photoscene](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/reality-capture/v1/reference/http/photoscene-POST) endpoint before uploading images to it, for example, like so:

```sh
curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/photo-to-3d/v1/photoscene' \
  -X 'POST' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6...' \
  -d 'scenename=testscene' \
  -d 'format=rcm,rcs,ortho' \
  -d 'metadata_name[0]=targetcs' \
  -d 'metadata_value[0]=UTM84-32N'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on the same issue for a while, but I realized it was the same issue mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73161325/11502399).

There's some discrepancy between the tutorials and the actual docs, and adding `"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` to the header seems to fix this issue.