# Why am I getting error code 28 'Scene name cannot be empty' when trying to add a photoscene?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am trying to complete the photo to 3D walkthrough and every time I try to add a photoscene I receive error 28 'Scene name cannot be empty'

In the code there clearly is a scene name.  I've not altered the code otherwise.  What can I try to get around this issue?

[Photo to 3D walkthrough code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpBtd.png)

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lji4d.png)

Comment: Please try to write as much as possible your code / error messages into your question instead of linking pictures. To answer your question, I think you should not use `querystring` to `stringify` your payload as it's not a query. You should use `JSON.stringify()` instead. Can you give it a try ?

Comment: That does seem to make a difference in the request but same response-
Request with JSON.stringify() 
 method: 'post',
    url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/photo-to-3d/v1/photoscene',
    data: '{"scenename":"myscenename","format":"rcm"}'

Request with querystring.stringify()
 method: 'post',
    url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/photo-to-3d/v1/photoscene',
    data: '"scenename=myscenename&format=rcm"'

response in both cases
  data: {
    Usage: '0.5022120475769',
    Resource: '/photoscene',
    Error: { code: '28', msg: 'Scene name cannot be empty' }
  }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My buddy Drew pointed me back to the documentation and found a discrepancy between Content-Type in the docs vs the sample code.  Sample code had application/json and the docs have application/x-www-form-urlencoded.  Updated sample code and worked successfully!