# Reality Capture API : Specified Photoscene ID doesn't exist in the database

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-realitycapture

I am posting below request to https://developer.api.autodesk.com/photo-to-3d/v1/file with the files and the photosceneId which I obtained from the previous step 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/photo-to-3d/v1/photoscene', but I am still getting an error stating Photoscene Id does not exist

I am not sure why the Id which the app gave to me does not exist in their Database.

I would like the images to be uploaded and success message to be received.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the error or at least the sceneId that creates you the problem?

Comment: had a similar problem, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76038887/11502399) solve your issue?